# EAGLE Matched Length Pairs / Groups

Tags: layout, eaglecad, constraints

What facilities does EAGLE CAD have for helping to do layout with matched length groups and differential pairs? Can you apply such a constraint in the auto-router? As a follow-on to this, what (other) free Electrical CAD tools support this type of feature?

**Edit**
If you don't believe any free CAD packages support this design feature, what are some low-cost options that do support it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eagle actually has **both** of these features as of version 6. From their website:

> **Benefit from differential pair routing and automatic meanders**
>
> Special signals can be routed with exactly the same length.
>   Differential pair routing is used for pairs of differential (equal and
>   opposite) signals across the board to create a balanced transmission
>   system. Creating meanders helps users automatically give a signal a
>   certain length in the PCB. Meanders in traces are used to increase
>   delay times in high speed digital circuits.

http://www.cadsoftusa.com/eagle-pcb-design-software/new-in-v6/?language=en (halfway down)

See for yourself.

The Meander button:

[image]

Length matching of a differential pair (from manual):

[image]

I don't actually know how to implement these techniques, but I can point you to the documentation. Check the manual (warning 300+ page PDF) on page 175 to 178 - http://www.cadsoft.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/V6_manual_en.pdf

Comment: awesome, I'm still using 5.11, but this may be a good reason to update!

Comment: Yeah, version 6 is really cool. You will probably get a discount for upgrading too.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I do equal length differential pair routing in Eagle CAD:

1. Name traces `D_P` and `D_N` (or something `_N` and `_P` - seems like Eagle CAD needs the suffix).
2. Create net class in schematic and add both traces to it
3. Route the traces, either together (the default) or separately (type `ESC` and Eagle CAD will stop routing the second trace).
4. In board view, type `run length D_*` in the command window
5. In the dialog box that comes up, click on longer pair length, copy it (`Command-C` works on my Mac)
6. Type `meander [copied length]mm`, but replace `[copied length]` with the value you just copied (`Command-V` to paste works on my Mac) into the command window. `mm` means millimeters, `length.ulp` measures in mm
7. Click on the shorter trace to meander it.
8. Move mouse to meander the shorter trace until its length is the same as the longer trace and the meander pattern is to your liking.

The [Eagle Cad v6 Manual](http://www.cadsoft.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/V6_manual_en.pdf) p175-178 helps.

Comment: `run meander [length]mm` throws an error: `cannot open 'meander.ulp'`. I was checking my `ulp` directories but I could not find any `meander.upl`. I usually use Eagle 6.1.0 but even with 7.6.0 no luck. Your answers sounded like it was already included in the default installation. Do I have to download it somewhere?

Comment: @user3097432 My instructions were wrong, just updated them - you don't need the 'run', just type 'meander [length]mm' but replace the [length] with the number of mm you need.